# Alembic doesn't create code in migrations for creating tables (using FastAPI and sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

here is database code that I try to migrate, it's supposed to be database for little cervice

```
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Integer, MetaData, String, Table,
                        create_engine, ARRAY, ForeignKey, DateTime, TIMESTAMP, PrimaryKeyConstraint)


from databases import Database
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
import asyncio

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+asyncpg://myuser:mypassword@localhost:myport/mydatabase"
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = MetaData()
AsyncSessionLocal = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
)

Base = declarative_base()


class Material(Base):
    __tablename__ = "materials"
    id_material = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    id_type = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("material_types.id_type"))
    material_type = relationship("MaterialType", secondary="coffin_materials", back_populates="materials")


class MaterialType(Base):
    __tablename__ = "material_types"
    id_type = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    materials = relationship("Material", back_populates="material_type")


class Coffin(Base):
    __tablename__ = "coffins"
    id_coffin = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    price = Column(Integer)
    length = Column(Integer)
    width = Column(Integer)
    quantity = Column(Integer)
    materials = relationship("Material", secondary="coffin_materials")


class CoffinMaterial(Base):
    __tablename__ = "coffin_materials"
    id_coffin = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("coffins.id_coffin"), primary_key=True)
    id_material = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("materials.id_material"), primary_key=True)
    PrimaryKeyConstraint("id_coffin", "id_material", name="pk_coffin_materials")


async def create_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(metadata.create_all)
# Викликати цю функцію для асинхронного створення таблиць

asyncio.run(create_tables())


database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
```

I tried to create a database with many to many relationsip and when I made this relationsip things gone bad
and here is my env.py code

```
import asyncio
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine

from app.api.db_model import metadata, DATABASE_URL


# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", DATABASE_URL)

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.

fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


async def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    config_section = config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
    config_section["sqlalchemy.url"] = "postgresql+asyncpg://myuser:mypassword@localhost:myport/mydatabase"
    connectable = AsyncEngine(engine_from_config(
        config_section,
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    ))

    def do_migrations(connection):
        context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()

    async with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

        await connection.run_sync(do_migrations)
    # with connectable.connect() as connection:
    #     context.configure(
    #         connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
    #     )
    #
    #     with context.begin_transaction():
    #         context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    asyncio.run(run_migrations_online())
```

and when I try to make migration I get this migration code -

```
"""first_migration

Revision ID: 5862798bf83c
Revises: 
Create Date: 2024-01-06 15:57:38.226984

"""
from typing import Sequence, Union

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision: str = '5862798bf83c'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = None
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    pass


def downgrade() -> None:
    pass
```

I tried to reinstall alembic, make new project but that didn't do anything, maybe you can help me with this issue, google and chatgpt didn't get me answers...

Comment: How are you running alembic? Unless you give the `--autogenerate` argument to `revision`, an empty migration will be created and you're expected to fill it out yourself.

Comment: I'm using --autogenerate, it doesn't work

Comment: You're using the ORM mode, so you have to explicitly use the `metadata` object from your `Base`, instead of using an empty metadata object (you're just creating an object and not associating anything with it). `from app.api.db_model import Base` and then `target_metadata = Base.metadata`.